# Morphisms from quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x], \left<f(x)\right>$ be the ideal it generates. Let $R$ be a ring. Prove that giving a ring homomorphsim $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\left<f(x)\right> \rightarrow R$ is equivalent to give a root of $f(x)$ in $R.$ Also, prove that the function $\phi \mapsto \phi(\bar{x})$ from set of homomorphism to the set of roots of $f(x)$ in $R$ is bijective.

I have shown the first part of the question. But I am stuck on the bijectivity part. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Given a root of $f$ in $R$, what do you think the homomorphism would be? Write down a plausible inverse map and show that they indeed are inverses of one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Injectivity: since there is only one ring homomorphism $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z[x]/(f(x))$, namely the composition $\mathbb Z \hookrightarrow \mathbb Z[x] \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb Z[x]/(f(x))$, any ring homomorphism $\mathbb Z[x]/(f(x)) \to R$ is completely determined by its value in $\bar x$.
- Surjectivity: Take $\alpha \in R$ such that $f(\alpha)=0_R$. Then prove that the evaluation map $$\operatorname{ev}_\alpha : \mathbb Z[x] \to R; \ p(x) \mapsto p(\alpha)$$ factors through $\mathbb Z[x] \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb Z[x]/(f(x))$.

Comment: Thank you! I have written draft solution ealier today. For the surjectiveity part, can we just define the evaluation map on the quotient ring? That will be homomorphism.

Comment: Well, you need to check that $\phi_\alpha : \mathbb Z[x]/(f(x)) \to R$ given by $\overline{p(x)} \mapsto p(\alpha)$ is well-defined (that is, $\overline{p_1(x)} = \overline{p_2(x)} \implies p_1(\alpha) = p_2(\alpha)$).

Comment: Thank you. I have added that.